# i get this notification in terminal, when want to run dart in terminal , I'm a beginner

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgCFz.png)

notif in terminal:
The command dasar_dartpt2.dart was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\dasar_dartpt2.dart". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a `.dart` file directly, you would need to run `dart dasar_dartpt2.dart` (and for this to work, your Dart SDK needs to be listed in your `PATH` environment variable).

A simpler way to run the script is to click the `Run` link just above your `main` function. Or you can use the `Debug` link which will run with a debugger that will let you debug and inspect the script at runtime. Using these links (or the `Run` menu in VS Code) passes the request to the Dart extension which can provide features you won't get when just running the script directly in a terminal.